# before action with user_signed_in? check in application controller makes DB call and and returns user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Tried to customize the sign-in behaviour by following https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/#configuring-controllers.

with Rails 5.2.2, ruby 2.5.3, devise 4.6.1.

I have used user_signed_in? with before_action in the application_controller.rb which makes a select query and results in the current_user object.

is this mean user signed in? is this the expected behaviour?

if so how can I check user-signed-in in the application_controller where I need to set application-level values based on the user detail.

Help me and correct me if I am doing wrong.

Did not make any change in the default **devise.rb**

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :profiles
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
  root to: "profiles#index"
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true
  before_action :simple_call, if: proc { user_signed_in? }
  ## USER BELOW LINE AS WELL BY COMMENTING ABOVE RESULTS SAME
  #before_action :simple_call, if: proc { current_user.present? }
  def  simple_call
    p '--------CURRENT_USER----'
    p current_user
  end
end
```

**users/sessions_controller.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    p 'this line is printing after before action'
    super do |resource|
     p 'this is inside create'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

**Log** during sign in

```
Started GET "/" for 172.xx.xx.xx at 2019-02-13 19:25:57 +0530
Cannot render console from 172.xx.xx.xx! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"Y01fmO/qtAbNO7QcS6lXc                                                         bOj0vSWXEnlYGlnrNT7TDOm4/yoJRWfSdknzpUMK2mKeMGrQaCEJa07Tn6I10Z2QQ==", "u                                                         ser"=>{"email"=>"k@t.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0                                                         "}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email                                                         " = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "k@t.com"], ["LIMI                                                         T", 1]]
  â³ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3
"--------CURRENT_USER----"
#<User id: 1, email: "k@t.com", created_at: "2019-02-13 13:16:34", upd                                                         ated_at: "2019-02-13 13:16:34">
"this line is printing after before action"
"this is inside create"
Redirected to http://172.xx.xx.xx:3004/
Completed 302 Found in 141ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

**UPDATE**

Refer this discussion. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4951

I believe this would be fixed in the upcoming releases.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to call `before_filter :authenticate_user!` before your `user_signed_in?` check will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Added `before_filter :authenticate_user!` before `user_signed_in?` in the `application_controller.rb`. This did not make any difference. Still this user_signed_in? returns the current_user before it goes to sessions_controler's create method.

Comment: @User `user_signed_in?` should be returning true or false, and will be behaving as it should so long as you call `authenticate_user` beforehand. What is actually going wrong in your example? Your "simple call" retrieves the current user and prints it, that matches your logs, I'm not understanding the problem.

Comment: before_action with `:authenticate_user!` or `user_signed_in?` returns true before it reaches signin(create) method in the session controller. After signin, it should return true, but why has it return true before reaching create method, which means user signed-in before it reaches the create method? I expect it should not call the :simple_call during sign-in.

Comment: Presumably because you're already signed in! Clear your cookies and try again. Go check the authenticate_user method code on the devise repo and see what it's doing. It's VERY unlikely devise is misbehaving.

Comment: I found this discussion - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4951  . A discussion is going on to make this change.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I would probably approach this by adding my own helper to devise (or a separate method elsewhere) that calls "warden.authenticated" instead of authenticate, which ought to return false in your case!